# Docker build looses everything that was done in RUN sequence

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I am trying to build Wordpress docker image and image is build but there are few things that don't make sense to me. I using Jenkins pipeline and AWS ECR. Here is my docker file:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

ADD --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html/

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/wp-content/cache &&\
    ls -al /var/www/html/wp-content/cache &&\
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html &&\
    find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; &&\
    find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; &&\
    chmod 600 /var/www/html/wp-config.php &&\
    ls -al /var/www/html/wp-config.php &&\
    chmod 644 /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

I inserted few LS commands in RUN as a control so here is the output on Jenkins pipeline

```
Step 1/3 : FROM wordpress:latest
latest: Pulling from library/wordpress
Digest: sha256:add5816d1c04fdf1509e298af0ec16f8485cd165292bd4245ffdbb9a1db87429
Status: Image is up to date for wordpress:latest
 ---> b9db6e8f3175
Step 2/3 : ADD --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html/
 ---> 43e8cb24bfe0
Step 3/3 : RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/wp-content/cache &&    ls -al /var/www/html/wp-content/cache &&    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html &&    find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; &&    find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; &&    chmod 600 /var/www/html/wp-config.php &&    ls -al /var/www/html/wp-config.php &&    chmod 644 /var/www/html/.htaccess
 ---> Running in ba6777eceeb2
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Dec 17 21:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 17 21:54 ..
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 4060 Dec 17 21:54 /var/www/html/wp-config.php
Removing intermediate container ba6777eceeb2
 ---> 60434b05bfde
Successfully built 60434b05bfde
Successfully tagged yyyyy.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx_wordpress:wordpress_develop_94ae0c780964ddbe7e15e978ad6b05814f269690
```

Now you would expect that when I run container I have those directories created and file permission set like in Jenkins output but that is not the case.

```
root@03eef2275a79:/var/www/html# ls -l /var/www/html/wp-config.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 4078 Dec 17 21:55 /var/www/html/wp-config.php
```

`ADD --chown=www-data:www-data` helped in Dockerfile since RUN didn't work but obviously something is not picking up stuff that I do in RUN and I have no idea why.

Maybe it's related, I created .dockerignore file in root of my repo and it's getting ignored at docker build stage. Everything I don't want in the image is there (.git .gitignore ...). Very frustrating ! Can't say I am experienced Docker guru but obviously I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you post your docker command to start the container please?

Comment: I am using docker-compose.yaml in combination with AWS codedeploy agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place files in `/usr/src/wordpress` instead of `/var/www/html`. That's because the html directory is defined as a VOLUME in the parent image, and changes in a RUN step are applied to a temporary volume that does not get captured in the resulting image layers. The entrypoint for the WordPress image does a copy from `/usr/src/wordpress` when the volume is not configured.

Comment: Thanks! That was it